# How can I get the last two digits of a number, using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, numbers, substr

How can I get a value from particular number?

Lets say number is `20040819`. I want to get last two digit i.e `19` using Perl.

Comment: Your number looks like a date (Aug 19, 2004) from which you are extracting the day of month.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a DateTime library (like, say, [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime)) instead of manually parsing date strings.

Answer (score 12):

```
my $x = 20040819;
print $x % 100, "\n";
print substr($x, -2);
```

Comment: The `%` option is the most natural in my opinion.

Comment: I find the substr more explicit.

Answer (score 4):

Benoit's answer is on the mark and one I would use, but in order to do this with a pattern search as you suggested in your title, you would do:

```
my $x = 20040819;
if ($x =~ /\d*(\d{2})/)
{
    $lastTwo = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
substr("20040819", -2);
```

or you can use **[Regexp::Common::time](http://search.cpan.org/~roode/Regexp-Common-time-0.01/time.pm#Year-Month-Day_order)** - Date and time regular expressions like

```
use strict;
use Regexp::Common qw(time);


my $str = '20040819' ;

if ($str =~ $RE{time}{YMD}{-keep})
{
  my $day = $4; # output 19

  #$1 the entire match

  #$2 the year

  #$3 the month

  #$4 the day
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to go beyond and show how to extract a YYYYMMDD format date into a year, month, and date:

```
my $str = '20040819';
my ($year, $month, $date) = $str =~ /^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/;
```

You can check for `defined $year`, etc., to figure out if the match worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $num = 20040819;
my $i = 0;
if ($num =~ m/([0-9]{2})$/) {
    $i = $1;
}
print $i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
my $x = 20040819;
$x =~ /(\d{2})\b/;
my $last_two_digits = $1;
```

the `\b` matches a word boundary.

Comment: Have you heard about Unicode? `\d` matches more than just ASCII digits (`[0-9]`): indian digits and others...

Comment: Maybe we'll get the /a flag in Perl 5.14 though :)

Comment: @briandfoy We did. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
my $number = '20040819';
my @digits = split //, $number;
print join('', splice @digits, -2, 2);
```

Comment: This soluting gives an list containing two one-character strings: `('1', '9')`.

Comment: Fixed using `join`, though I wonder if he meant to use `substr`?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for you:

```
my $number = 20040819;
my ($pick) = $number =~ m/(\d{2})$/;
print "$pick\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$x=20040819-int(20040819/100)*100;
```